# Best way to write a 'GET' API endpoint to receive date object which could be null [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, api

assuming I have an "GET" endpoint which receive two parameter startdate and enddate.

now we all know start date can be null sometime and front-end will construct the request as below

```
  Accounts/Statements/filter?startdate=null&enddate=xxxxxx.xxx.xxZ
```

Here is my question:

what is the best way to build the API endpoint. (in c# manner)

the API function will looks like this:

```
  [HttpGet("Accounts/Statements/filter")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatementsFilter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

In this case, If startDate as null, it will receive as the 01/01/0001

Or

```
  [HttpGet("Accounts/Statements/filter")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatementsFilter(string startDate, string endDate)
```

In this case, startDate will receive as a string null which I need to carefully converted into a Date Object to use later or treat as null.

Or

```
  [HttpGet("Accounts/Statements/filter")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatementsFilter([FromBody] DateObj dateObj)
```

in this case, require the frontend to change and send the parameter in the http request body so we can use DateTime? as param?

What do you guys think?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` will definitely help.

Comment: I personally would perfer the second notation because it doesnt really depend on the .Net model binder for parsing the dates. You get full control on which date formats you accept. I have had a thing where multiple different client send different formats of dates :D Its hard to enforce a certain format from possible every client connecting to the API and the .NET model binder assumes MM/DD/YYYY formats if you havent configured anything regarding culture or special model binder

Comment: @JochemVanHespen that would be an extremely bad idea. The standard way of passing dates is ISO8601. That's how .NET itself both sends and receives date values

Comment: *Don't* use strings. Use `DateTime?`. In .NET 6 and later you can use `DateOnly?`. The [RFC3339 standard date format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6), used in OpenAPI and expected by all clients, is ISO8601, ie `YYYY-MM-DD...`. .NET itself will serialize dates to ISO8601 and automatically parse ISO8601 strings to dates

Comment: thanks for all the input. I am really appreciated. it really helps me understand the Date in .Net alot

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to do something like this

```
[HttpGet("Accounts/Statements/filter")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetStatementsFilter([FromQuery] DateTime? startDate, [FromQuery] DateTime endDate)
```

So in this case, startDate will be optional for the frontend and you can easily check for null on startDate.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://BASE_URL/Accounts/Statements/filter?endDate=2022-12-12' \
  -H 'accept: */*'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used Datetime? before However in my one of try. The startDate receive as null whatever I pass from front-end or not. but it maybe it's my end of problem. I will probably check again.